# How to run rabbitmqctl commands on remote machine?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl, rabbitmqadmin

I have rabbitmq docker container, running on different machine. What I want to do is execute rabbitmqctl command using shell script from another machine. I am newbie to rabbitmq, need guidance of experts

I have used rabbitmqadmin with the option of -H to connect to remote server. I am able to connect and perform rabbitmqadmin commands. But there is no option for rabbitmqctl to connect to a remote server.

$ rabbitmqadmin -H 127.2.2.1 -u abc -p abc list vhosts

$ rabbitmqctl add_vhost xyz

I want to execute command rabbitmqctl on remote machine. rabbitmqadmin does work.

How can I make rabbitmqctl work in the same way. Please guide.

Answer (score 5):

`rabbitmqadmin` uses the [HTTP API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api), so it is enough to reach the http endpoint.

`rabbitmqctl` uses the erlang distribution, and in order to work it needs the same `.erlang.cookie` installed on the remote machine.

you can use `-n` paramenter in this way:

```
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@remotemachine
```

Check the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#OPTIONS) for more details